# Model is not updated

Tags: python, django

I want to put data into an excel worksheet.

I wrote the following code:

```
data_dict ={}
data_dict =defaultdict(dict)
def try_to_int(arg):
    try:
        return int(arg)
    except:
        return arg

def main():
    book4 = xlrd.open_workbook('./data/excel1.xlsx')
    sheet4 = book4.sheet_by_index(0)

    tag_list = sheet4.row_values(0)[1:]
    for row_index in range(1, sheet4.nrows):
        row = sheet4.row_values(row_index)[1:]
        row = list(map(try_to_int, row))
        value = dict(zip(tag_list, row))

        data_dict[value['age']].update(value)

        user2 = User.objects.filter(name=data_dict['name'])
        print(user2)
        if user2:
            if data_dict['name'] == 'Tom':
                user2.update(close_rate_under_300_ny = data_dict['300'],
                close_rate_under_700_ny = data_dict['d700'],
                close_rate_upper_700_ny = data_dictt['u700'])
            elif data_dict['name'] == 'John':
                user2.update(close_rate_under_300_eu = data_dict['300'],
                close_rate_under_700_eu = data_dict['d700'],
                close_rate_upper_700_eu = data_dict['u700'])
            elif data_dict['name'] == 'Blear':
                user2.update(close_rate_under_300_uk = data_dict['300'],
                close_rate_under_700_uk = data_dict['d700'],
                close_rate_upper_700_uk = data_dict['u700'])
            else:
                user2.update(close_rate_under_300_ch=data_dict['300'],
                close_rate_under_700_ch = data_dict['d700'],
                close_rate_upper_700_ch = data_dict['u700'])

main()
```

In print(user2), many `<QuerySet []>` were shown. So I think maybe user2 cannot be gotten.
Furthermore, in if-else statement of `if data_dict['name'] == 'Tom':`,user2 is not updated.

What is wrong in my code? By the way, `data_dict` is gotten normally.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using a custom User model. So it would be more clear if you gave the definition of User class and its methods.

From what I understood, I think you need to use

```
  user2 = User.objects.get(name=data_dict['name'])
```

Instead of:

```
  user2 = User.objects.filter(name=data_dict['name'])
```

filter() returns a Queryset which contains objects that satisfy the specified filter.

So you need to use a unique attribute of users like 'username' or an 'id' in order to get a single user. using name will return multiple objects if the table has more than one user with the same name.

And for updating the user (since you havent given the definition of update), try:

```
  if user2:
      if data_dict['name'] == 'Tom':
          user2.close_rate_under_300_ny = data_dict['300']
          user2.close_rate_under_700_ny = data_dict['d700']
          user2.close_rate_upper_700_ny = data_dictt['u700']
          user2.save()
      elif data_dict['name'] == 'John':
          user2.close_rate_under_300_eu = data_dict['300']
          user2.close_rate_under_700_eu = data_dict['d700']
          user2.close_rate_upper_700_eu = data_dict['u700']
          user2.save()
      elif data_dict['name'] == 'Blear':
          user2.close_rate_under_300_uk = data_dict['300']
          user2.close_rate_under_700_uk = data_dict['d700']
          user2.close_rate_upper_700_uk = data_dict['u700']
          user2.save()
      else:
          user2.close_rate_under_300_ch=data_dict['300']
          user2.close_rate_under_700_ch = data_dict['d700']
          user2.close_rate_upper_700_ch = data_dict['u700']
          user2.save()
```

instead of

```
  if user2:
        if data_dict['name'] == 'Tom':
            user2.update(close_rate_under_300_ny = data_dict['300'],
            close_rate_under_700_ny = data_dict['d700'],
            close_rate_upper_700_ny = data_dictt['u700'])
        elif data_dict['name'] == 'John':
            user2.update(close_rate_under_300_eu = data_dict['300'],
            close_rate_under_700_eu = data_dict['d700'],
            close_rate_upper_700_eu = data_dict['u700'])
        elif data_dict['name'] == 'Blear':
            user2.update(close_rate_under_300_uk = data_dict['300'],
            close_rate_under_700_uk = data_dict['d700'],
            close_rate_upper_700_uk = data_dict['u700'])
        else:
            user2.update(close_rate_under_300_ch=data_dict['300'],
            close_rate_under_700_ch = data_dict['d700'],
            close_rate_upper_700_ch = data_dict['u700'])
```

Comment: thx,ur answer.I wrote ur code,but app.models.DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist. error happens.How should I fix this?

Comment: That means there is no user with that particular name on your database. Did you populate the database? You have to add some Users first before querying. Try your query with './manage.py shell' first and see what happens.